# How to solve this type of equation: $x + \frac{15x}{100} = 11.90$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I need to find the value of a variable that adding 15% of that variable is equal to a number I have, for example:

$$x + \frac{15x}{100} = 11.90$$

What kind of formula is used to solve this equation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, multiply the equation with $100$. Then you will have an equation that looks like
$$a\cdot x = b$$
where $A$ and $b$ are some numbers. Then, solve the equation with $a$.

Answer (score 0):

First, make everything into one big fraction.
$$x+\frac{15x}{100}=11.9$$
$$x+\frac{3x}{20}=11.9$$
$$\frac{20x}{20}+\frac{3x}{20}=11.9$$
$$\frac{20x+3x}{20}=11.9$$
$$=\frac{23x}{20}=11.9$$
Multiply by $20$ on both sides:
$$23x=11.9\times 20=238$$
Divide by $23$ on both sides:
$$x=\frac{238}{23}$$
You cannot simplify this any further. Therefore the solution is:
$$\color{green}{\boxed{x=\dfrac{238}{23}}}$$